# Merging cells in jasper using expression

Tags: jasper-reports, report, expression

If I have table like this:

```
ID   |  details
___________________
1    |  A
2    |  B
3    |  C
4    |  D
5    |  E
6    |  F
6    |  G
```

and I want to show the table in jasper like this:

```
ID   |  details
___________________
1    |  A
2    |  B
3    |  C
4    |  D
5    |  E
6    |  F,G
```

if the detail have same id then the detail cells is merged

What kind of expression can I use to accomplish that in jasper (not in query)? I am using jasper 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by **grouping** on `$F{ID}`, using a [JRAbstractScriptlet](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRAbstractScriptlet.html) to concat the `$F{detail}` strings and displaying the result in the `groupFooter` band

Example of **Scriptlet**

```
public class Scriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {

  public void afterDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException
  {
    String details = (String)this.getVariableValue("detailsWithId");
    String detail = (String)this.getFieldValue("detail");
    StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
    if (details != null)
    {
        sbuffer.append(details);
        sbuffer.append(", ");
    }
    sbuffer.append(detail);
    this.setVariableValue("detailsWithId", sbuffer.toString());
  }
}
```

Example of **jrxml**, report, note the `scriptletClass="Scriptlet"` in `jasperReport` tag (the class `Scriptlet` needs to be in class path)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Example2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" scriptletClass="Scriptlet" uuid="ca579c38-1e4f-4993-a020-efcea9d1096e">
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/report/entry]]>
</queryString>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="detail" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[detail]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<variable name="detailsWithId" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Group" resetGroup="id" calculation="System">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<group name="id">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="20">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="19ec4996-dee5-461e-bc61-2bf967632a9e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{detailsWithId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="f0f77e03-d040-4628-94b3-e1506e713399"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="bee3aa66-130d-4f05-8bb2-55e57c068ecc"/>
            <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="9b4d86d1-4904-4854-b723-6fe62df170ce"/>
            <text><![CDATA[details]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

Example of **datasource**

```
<report>
<entry><id>1</id><detail>A</detail></entry>
<entry><id>2</id><detail>B</detail></entry>
<entry><id>3</id><detail>C</detail></entry>
<entry><id>4</id><detail>D</detail></entry>
<entry><id>5</id><detail>E</detail></entry>
<entry><id>6</id><detail>F</detail></entry>
<entry><id>6</id><detail>G</detail></entry>
</report>
```

**Result**:

[image: PDF RESULT]